# HUE Web UI will not login first time

Tags: user-interface, web, hadoop, hue

I've installed CDH 4.2.1 and now I'm trying to access `HUE Web UI` for the first time. I enter a new user name and password, click `Sign Up`, and wait and wait and nothing happens 20 minutes. If I open another window and try to access the login page then I get a message that the database is locked.

I'm running on a single node. And following is the error message for the second window:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.2.1-1.cdh4.2.1.p0.5/share/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/eventlet-0.9.14-py2.6.egg/eventlet/wsgi.py", line 336, in handle_one_response
    result = self.application(self.environ, start_response)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.2.1-1.cdh4.2.1.p0.5/share/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.6.egg/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 245, in __call__
    response = middleware_method(request, response)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.2.1-1.cdh4.2.1.p0.5/share/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.6.egg/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py", line 36, in process_response
    request.session.save()
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.2.1-1.cdh4.2.1.p0.5/share/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.6.egg/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py", line 63, in save
    obj.save(force_insert=must_create, using=using)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.2.1-1.cdh4.2.1.p0.5/share/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 434, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.2.1-1.cdh4.2.1.p0.5/share/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 500, in save_base
    rows = manager.using(using).filter(pk=pk_val)._update(values)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.2.1-1.cdh4.2.1.p0.5/share/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 491, in _update
    return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(None)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.2.1-1.cdh4.2.1.p0.5/share/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 861, in execute_sql
    cursor = super(SQLUpdateCompiler, self).execute_sql(result_type)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.2.1-1.cdh4.2.1.p0.5/share/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 727, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.2.1-1.cdh4.2.1.p0.5/share/hue/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.6.egg/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 200, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
DatabaseError: database is locked
```

Any idea?

Thank you,

Roberto.

Answer (score 0):

The error here means it is trying to connect to Sqlite and fails as the first connection is still not finished (and Sqlite is not concurrent) so it is not very useful here.

If would look in the hue logs, especially 'runcpserver.log' if there is more information.

Adding 'export DESKTOP_DEBUG=1' in the environment and restarting Hue might give more details.

I would go on `http://HUE_SERVER:HUE_PORT/dump_config`, look at the 'database' value and delete the file and run a /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.2.1-1.cdh4.2.1.p0.5/share/hue syncb or sync database if in CM.

It will recreate the database and make sure no other process is using it.

If it still does not work I would give a try to MySQL: http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/latest/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_15_8.html